# A syntactic approach to possessives

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology, phrase-structure, possession

I am currently writing an essay in linguistic typology on possessives. I got stuck in the last part, in which I am supposed to present a syntactic approach to the structure of possessives. I should find an example in the literature and simply present the approach in 300 words and draw an example tree...
I've found an approach that words with predicate-movement, but the article is quite difficult to understand, so if anybody knows a different approach to the topic, I would very glad to hear about it...

Answer (score 6):

On the basis of Ockham's Razor, why not try out [McCawley 1999](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226556298), specifically, Ch 12 (*The Structure of Noun Phrases*) part c. (*Genitives*) pp 399-406.

He lays out all the possible structures, and the arguments for and against them, very clearly. Mind you, he **does** expect that you understand how syntax works, as explained in the 11 previous chapters.